# Как использовать scrollTop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как использовать scrollTop,? Объясните принцип работы пожалуйста.

Comment: А почему не в бок?

Comment: @1stSentinel31YearPerlHist, это весело конечно, и я согласен что вопрос глупый, но лучше всего нормально один раз объяснить, чем просто тролить. [Нормы поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Comment: Извините пожалуйста) Просто настроние такое у меня

Comment: А вам Андрей, на будущие: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @1stSentinel31YearPerlHist та все ок, просто делу не поможет. я сам раньше не лучше вопросы задавал)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Элемент.scrollTop**

Свойство `scrollTop` считывает или устанавливает количество пикселей, прокрученных от верха элемента. `scrollTop` измеряет дистанцию от верха элемента до верхней точки видимого контента. Когда контент элемента не создаёт вертикальную прокрутку, его `scrollTop` равно `0`.

Источник: [Элемент.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

Пропишите значение `html` элементу: `document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;`